# What is the correct path to store a user specific credentials file?

Tags: configuration, home, dot-files, xdg-user-dirs

I guess `~/.config` (`XDG_CONFIG_HOME`) is not correct because that way users have to be constantly aware which files are safe to commit to their dotfiles repository.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put it next to your SSH key in `~/.ssh`? Sounds like it serves kind of the same purpose.

Alternatively, you could use something like Hashicorp Vault to store secrets.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the freedesktop.org's [Secret Storage Spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/secret-storage-spec/) ([Version 0.2 Working Draft](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/secret-service/latest/))

This way you can have the credentials saved in a keyring that is unlocked when the user logs in.